# how to store last 2 months data in local chache (not in local database) date wish in android in java

Tags: java, android, date, caching, local

Need to store past SEVEN months data in local(not in local database). First I need to store first
TWO months date wise data in local. After that if TWO months data exceeds then again need to call
api and store next TWO months data in local date wise and again for TWO months and lastly for 1
month as it is last SEVEB month data.
Same as (2+2+2+1).

this is the response below:

```
[
    {
        "value": 3.0,
        "date": "16032022"
    },
    {
        "value": 50.0,
        "date": "17032022"
    }
]
```

After storing data in local, I need to get the data from local cache (not database) weekly basis, that means have pass the startDate of week and endDate of week. what should be the way to work?

How to store locally and from fetch there weekly basis?

Comment: It is not a good idea to store that much data in SharedPreferences, better to use a database solution like Android Room.

Answer (score 0):

To save this info in local cache you can use `Shared Preferences` this can save relatively small collection of key-values.
The documentation [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java)

Example how save the data:

```
//Config your Shared Precerence
String sharedPreferenceName = "com.example.myapp.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY"
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref =
context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Save data
String preferenceKey = "data_id";
String defaultValue = "";
String jsonData = "[\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"value\": 3.0,\n" +
            "        \"date\": \"160/32/022\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"value\": 50.0,\n" +
            "        \"date\": \"17/03/2022\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "]";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString(preferenceKey, jsonData);
editor.apply();

//get data
String data = sharedPref.getString(preferenceKey, defaultValue);
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonArray jsonArray = gson.fromJson(data, JsonArray.class);

//Here iterate the array and validate the date
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
String dateString = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("date").getAsString();
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dateString);
Date currentDate = new Date();
//to this (get days elapsed) use joda-time-2.5
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time
//implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.10.14'
int daysElapsed = Days.daysBetween(
        new LocalDate(date.getTime()),
        new LocalDate(currentDate.getTime())).getDays();
        
if (daysElapsed > 60) {
    //the data exceeds TWO months
    //Call the API
} else {
    //do nothing
}
}
```